# Mobile web: numeric input + math operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have HTML mobile web page containing form inputs.

I need to use NUMERIC keypad on android and iphone devices, but attribute type="number" doesnt look like right solution for me because it eliminates all numeric operations represented by "+" "-" "/" "*"

So i need co combine numeric keypad on mobile devices and allow all math operators. How ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like iOS has the + key option but this leads to another sub-menu keyboard

iOS should popup this keyboard:

**iOS Input `type="number"`**

[image]

Android 2.2 should popup this keyboard (Other versions of Android may have different options):

**Android 2.2 Input `type="number"`**

[image]

[Source](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm)